# Model's Limbs Shortening/Flattening When Bent

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I recently gave a model I've been working on a rig with Rigify. Although I know the weight paint needs to be adjusted along with upping the vertices, whenever I bend a limb such as a forearm, everything below the point of bending flattens and shortens. The farther your bend, the more exaggerated it becomes. Is this purely related to needing to adjust the weight paint and add more vertices or is there something else wrong? If it is just the weight paint and vertices, how do I remedy this problem? Below is a link to the model:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUrLia-hmcwaU4eMz7sJOY7kR4WcfUfK/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Select your armature in *Object* mode, as you can see it has been scaled and therefore it stretches your mesh as soon as you move bones, so just apply the scale with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and it will work fine.

[image]

As for your hair rigging, your hair is controlled by bones that are not supposed to control it, you need to assign it to the head vertex group:

Go in *Edit* mode, select the hair mesh (press <kbd>L</kbd> to automatically select the whole mesh):

[image]

- Go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, in the dropdown menu on the right of the vertex groups list, click on *Remove From All Groups*:

[image]

- Select the group called *Spine006* (it's the group that is controlled by your head bone, when you parent *With Automatic Weight*, vertex groups are automatically created with the name of the bone that is controlling them) and click on the *Assign* button:

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! You're a life-saver!

Comment: Also, when it comes to the hair bending oddly with the head bone, that's a weight paint issue, yes?

Comment: yes, select the hair mesh, go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, in the dropdown menu on the right of the vertex groups list, click on Remove From All Groups, then select the group called Spine006 and click on the Assign button

Comment: Would you mind showing me? I'm having a bit of difficulty, mainly with selecting all of the hair mesh and locating the correct panel

Comment: i've edited my answer, I hope it's clear  ;)

Comment: I can't say thank you enough! You've been a great help to me. I hope you have a great rest of your day/night!

Comment: you're welcome, good luck  ;)